# How can I detect if the current project is a root project from inside a dynamic task in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

This was originally asked by @daniel-c-sobral on Gitter:

> How can I detect if the current project is a root project from inside a dynamic task?

**Update**:

Talking to Daniel a bit more, he clarified:

> It’s a plugin that is changing `test` to run a task, but only on the root project.

So it seems like he wants to detect whether a particular task is scoped to the root project or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a couple of helper definitions:

```scala
val rootProjectRef: Def.Initialize[ProjectRef] = Def.setting {
  val rootBuildUri  = loadedBuild.value.root
  val rootProjectId = loadedBuild.value.units(rootBuildUri).root
  ProjectRef(rootBuildUri, rootProjectId)
}

val currentProjectRef: Def.Initialize[Task[ProjectRef]] =
  Def.task(Project.session(state.value).current)
```

We can fairly cleanly implement both the task to determine if the currently selected project is the (root) build's root project (which you can invoke from any other task, dynamic or not), as well as the more general "is this project the root project?" and "is this project the currently selected project?" questions:

```scala
val isRootProject        = settingKey[Boolean]("Is this the root project?")
val isCurrentProject     = taskKey[Boolean]("Is this the currently selected project?")
val isCurrentProjectRoot = taskKey[Boolean]("Is the currently select project the root project?")

inScope(Global)(Def.settings(
  isCurrentProjectRoot := currentProjectRef.value == rootProjectRef.value,
))

val commonSettings = Def.settings(
  isRootProject    := thisProjectRef.value == rootProjectRef.value,
  isCurrentProject := thisProjectRef.value == currentProjectRef.value,
)

lazy val root = project in file(".") settings commonSettings aggregate app
lazy val app  = project settings commonSettings
```

In action:

```scala
> show root / isRootProject
[info] true
> show app / isRootProject
[info] false
>
> show root / isCurrentProject
[info] true
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan 2020, 00:02:58
> show app / isCurrentProject
[info] false
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan 2020, 00:03:04
>
> project
[info] root (in build file:/s/t-sbt-amIRoot/)
> 
> show isCurrentProjectRoot
[info] true
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan 2020, 00:03:11
>
>
>
> project app
[info] Set current project to app (in build file:/s/t-sbt-amIRoot/)
>
> show root / isCurrentProject
[info] false
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan 2020, 00:03:34
> show app / isCurrentProject
[info] true
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan 2020, 00:03:37
>
> show isCurrentProjectRoot
[info] false
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan 2020, 00:03:42
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 22 Jan 2020, 22:04:43
```

A couple of things to note:

First, notice that `isRootProject` can be implemented as a setting, because it's an immutable value of the loaded build.

Secondly, note that scoping `isCurrentProjectRoot` is pointless (that's why it's global, as it has no dependencies on anything within a project), but not illegal, which might make it misleading, for instance:

```scala
> project /
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/s/t-sbt-amIRoot/)
> 
> show isCurrentProjectRoot
[info] true
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan 2020, 00:06:23
> 
> show app / isCurrentProjectRoot
[info] true
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 23 Jan 2020, 00:06:26
```

Comment: Nice. I like the `isRoot` implementation.

Comment: Reworked it, now based on some general utilities (that we could lift into sbt).

Comment: It seems `currentProjectRef` is `Project.current(state.value)`, a small shortcut to the same thing.

Comment: Hi @DaleWijnand, I am very very sorry for adding something that is not related to this question, but I really need your help - could you please kindly look at this question which I think you will be able to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854900/one-of-the-example-projects-listed-by-lightbend-is-not-working-for-larger-files. many many thanks! and sorry guys for hijacking the topic!

Answer (score 2):

#### isRoot

Here's my answer.

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.13.1"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val foo = taskKey[Int]("")
def whereAmI: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  foo := (Def.taskDyn {
    val r = resolvedScoped.value
    val st = state.value
    val structure = Project.extract(st).structure
    val isRoot = r.scope.project match {
      case Select(ref: ProjectRef) =>
        structure.rootProject(ref.build) == ref.project
      case _ => false
    }
    if (isRoot) Def.task { 0 }
    else Def.task { 1 }
  }).value
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "hello",
    whereAmI,
  )

lazy val app = project
  .settings(
    name := "app",
    whereAmI,
  )
```

`resolvedScoped` key would evaluate to the resolved scoped key `Def.ScopedKey[_]`. The scope field is typed to be [Scope](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.3.7/main-settings/src/main/scala/sbt/Scope.scala), which contains `project: ScopeAxis[Reference]`. This will typically contain `ProjectRef`.

```scala
final case class ProjectRef(build: URI, project: String)
    extends ProjectReference
    with ResolvedReference
```

We can test the values of `build: URI` and `project: String` to see if they match those of root project or not.

#### How to test this

```
sbt:hello> show root/foo
[info] 0
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 22, 2020 2:50:34 PM
sbt:hello> show app/foo
[info] 1
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 22, 2020 2:50:39 PM
```

This dynamically returned `0` for root project but `1` for app.

#### isCurrent variant

After talking to Daniel, he said he might be interested in the current project:

> For one thing, there’s a lot of “root” in the API, but, more to the point, there’s the project where you are at when you start sbt.

Here's a variant that tests whether the dynamic task foo is running on the current project or not.

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.13.1"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example"

lazy val foo = taskKey[Int]("")
def whereAmI: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
  foo := (Def.taskDyn {
    val r = resolvedScoped.value
    val st = state.value
    val isCurrent = r.scope.project match {
      case Select(ref: ProjectRef) =>
        ref == Project.extract(st).currentRef
      case _ => false
    }
    if (isCurrent) Def.task { 2 }
    else Def.task { 3 }
  }).value
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "hello",
    whereAmI,
  )

lazy val app = project
  .settings(
    name := "app",
    whereAmI,
  )
```

Here's how it looks in the sbt shell:

```
sbt:hello> show root/foo
[info] 2
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 22, 2020 3:04:17 PM
sbt:hello> show app/foo
[info] 3
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 22, 2020 3:04:22 PM
```

Let's see what happens if you change the current project to `app`:

```
sbt:hello> project app
[info] Set current project to app (in build file:/private/tmp/hello/)
sbt:app> show root/foo
[info] 3
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 22, 2020 3:04:28 PM
sbt:app> show app/foo
[info] 2
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 22, 2020 3:04:34 P
```

Comment: `resolvedScoped` isn't the correct tool here, as it exists expressly to capture the the scope of the referencing key.  So I expect something like `fooAlias in app := foo in root` (and vice-versa) to give the wrong (opposite) answer.