# One of the example projects listed by Lightbend is not working for larger files

Tags: playframework, akka

I did post this same question at LightBend's discussion group [here](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/one-of-the-example-projects-listed-by-lightbend-is-not-working-for-larger-files/7387), but cannot get an answer that solves my issue. Since I am really anxious to know what is the problem here, let me again post this question here, hoping a big audience group might mean a better chance of getting an answer.

So basically, at this page, https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=play, we can find a list of example Play! projects. Among these examples, there is one project is about Java File Upload (https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=play&project=play-samples-play-java-fileupload-example). This project teaches the readers how to create a file uploader using Akka Streaming idea, therefore even when the file is large, we can still safely upload it without reading it as a whole into the memory.

This project works for small files, but when I try to upload a larger file, for example, which has a size about 15M, I will get a page says “The connection was reset”.

Now, in this example project, inside `application.conf` file, I see this,

```
# **Sets the maximum file size that can be uploaded to 1024k.**
# https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaBodyParsers#Content-length-limits
play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer=1024k
```

Indeed - if I upload any file that is smaller than 1024k, it will work, but anything larger than that, it will not work.

Now, I am very confused. Notice 1024k is the size of `maxMemoryBuffer`! This does not make sense to me because the whole idea of “streaming it”, is to be able to stream it with a much smaller memory buffer and without reading the whole file into the memory first. But the file size has to be smaller than `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer`??? this makes me think it might just read the whole file into memory …

I know I am wrong, but just don't know where I am wrong and what I have missed. I hope someone with a better idea can see this question and will kindly let me know what is happening… Thank you so much for the help!

**UPDATE:**

Let me add a little bit more information here. So if I upload a file that is larger than `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer`, the error message is the following (using Chrome):

```
This site can’t be reached
ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED
```

and here is what I see in the log:

```
[debug] a.h.i.u.StreamUtils$DelayCancellationStage$$anon$11 - Delaying cancellation for 1 minute
```

Hope this can be of some help??

Comment: The link you provided says: "_The memory buffer limit is configured using `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer`, [...] while the disk buffer limit is configured using `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer`, [...] These can both be configured in application.conf_". Have you tried the `maxDiskBuffer` setting?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos  - yes, I did try that. But its value did not matter and what really mattered was still `maxMemoryBuffer` - as long as the file that is being uploaded is larger than that, it will not work. Again, what I expect is a small memory buffer combined with a large `maxDiskBuffer`, and once the memory buffer is full, it will write out to the disk, and that is why it is "streaming", and that is why a 15G video can be easily uploaded without being loaded into memory as a whole first. But now, my file cannot be bigger than the memory buffer...that is just totally confusing to me.

Comment: Very strange, could it be a bug?

Comment: I am not sure. The project (including all the source code and config files) is downloaded from the link I gave in the question description, and I did not make any change.

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.conf` set;

```
play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=500MB
```

We needed this to allow video uploads to our play app. Default is 10M if you not set one.